# C++ Incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: c++

written below is my code for writing usernames and passwords to a file. Everything seems to be ok except for the createUser() function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "login.h"
#include <fstream>

std::string user;
std::string pass;

struct Users {
    std::string username;
    std::string password;
};

void createUser(user, pass) {
    Users new;
    new.username = user;
    new.password = pass;
    ofstream inFile;
    inFile.open("users.txt");
    inFile << User.username << User.password;
    inFile.close()
}

int main(){
    createUser(Users.username, Users.password);
    return 0;
}
```

The error here is "incomplete type is not allowed"
I am assuming it has to do something with the structure i have used but i dont exactly know what.
It also says that it expects a ";" after the { bracket at line 15 (void createUser(){)

Comment: typo: do not use `new`, it's a reserved word

Comment: if you've used `new` as the variable name in your code, that will probably be the source of a bug, maybe not the one you're seeing here

Comment: If you provide the exact error message, I can try to explain _why_ you got the error you did (copy-paste from compiler).

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Yes i did

Comment: Your compiler did not just say "incomplete type not allowed", it would also say line number, print out the erroneous line, show the character where it thought there was a mistake, etc. Just copy-paste whatever your compiler output to here.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso i have solved this problem, however the solution has created another problem. I have used #include <fstream> for writing to files and have a line ostream inFile; It seems to tell me "identifier "ofstream" is undefined (19, 2). Any idea on what that might be?

Comment: @Niko try `std::ofstream` instead. Lots of C++ things live in namespaces.

Comment: Also, please, please, just paste the whole error message in the future. It's a lot easier for me to help you based on what the compiler says than based on the parts of the error message you think are important. Plus I'm used to reading the compiler error messages.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso That worked, thank you! (Will post full error messages from now on).

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare the type in the createUser function:

```
void createUser(const std::string& user, const std::string& pass) {
```

Comment: It seems to have worked but can you explain why exactly does this happen?

Comment: @Niko C++ is statically typed, which means the types of variables and functions are known largely at compile time, not at runtime, and the compiler needs to be told the types of things you intend to use so that it can write the correct machine code. For example `x += y` can have _very_ different meanings when `x` or `y` are allowed to be `int`, `double,` `std::string`, etc, and the compiler needs to know types in order for your program to do the right thing, since type information largely doesn't exist at runtime.